mvn recognizes, then forgets, specific module
Right now I am able to mvn clean install a project successfully.
But when I mvn test-compile -X I see an unexpected module not found error.
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] module not found: org.codehaus.stax2
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  20.860 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-04-04T14:57:55-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project [removed]: Compilation failure
[ERROR] module not found: org.codehaus.stax2
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project [removed]: Compilation failure
module not found: org.codehaus.stax2

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:333)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
module not found: org.codehaus.stax2

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1220)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:187)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000 (MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run (MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute (DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:206)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:283)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:226)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:407)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:348)
[ERROR]

Some increasingly confusing breadcrumbs I have found:
1 Local m2 Repository Has Artifact
 ⚡ls ~/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/stax2-api/                                                                      
╭───┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬──────┬───────┬──────────────╮
│ # │                                    name                                     │ type │ size  │   modified   │
├───┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────┼───────┼──────────────┤
│ 0 │ /Users/pieter.benjamin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/stax2-api/3.1.4 │ dir  │ 224 B │ 6 months ago │
│ 1 │ /Users/pieter.benjamin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/stax2-api/4.2   │ dir  │ 224 B │ 8 months ago │
│ 2 │ /Users/pieter.benjamin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/stax2-api/4.2.1 │ dir  │ 352 B │ 2 weeks ago  │
╰───┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────┴───────┴──────────────╯

2 mvn dependency:list -DoutputAbsoluteArtifactFilename Shows the Module Resolved
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
...
[INFO]    org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.2.1:compile:/Users/pieter.benjamin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/stax2-api/4.2.1/stax2-api-4.2.1.jar -- module org.codehaus.stax2

3 mvn test -X Shows the Artifact Alongside Everything Else
[DEBUG]   (f) compilePath = [...,  /Users/pieter.benjamin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/stax2-api/4.2.1/stax2-api-4.2.1.jar, /Users/pieter.benjamin/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/woodstox/woodstox-core/6.5.1/woodstox-core-6.5.1.jar,...]
...
[DEBUG] Classpath:
...
[DEBUG]  /Users/pieter.benjamin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/stax2-api/4.2.1/stax2-api-4.2.1.jar
...
[DEBUG] Command line options:
[DEBUG] -d /Users/pieter.benjamin/.../target/classes -classpath /Users/pieter.benjamin/transforms.../target/classes:...:/Users/pieter.benjamin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/stax2-api/4.2.1/stax2-api-4.2.1.jar:...
...

What on earth could cause this? I notice from Item #2 the artifact org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.2.1:compile has the compile scope, so it's not like this is exclusively being loaded in at runtime.
edit:
4 Intellij Can Find the Artifact
In Intellij under Project -> External Libraries, there is an entry for Maven: org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:4.2.1 with several .java files (classes and interfaces as well as a file module-info.class which contains:
module org.codehaus.stax2 {
  requires java.xml;

  exports org.codehaus.stax2;
  exports org.codehaus.stax2.evt;
  exports org.codehaus.stax2.io;
  exports org.codehaus.stax2.osgi;
  exports org.codehaus.stax2.ri;
  exports org.codehaus.stax2.ri.dom;
  exports org.codehaus.stax2.ri.evt;
  exports org.codehaus.stax2.ri.typed;
  exports org.codehaus.stax2.typed;
  exports org.codehaus.stax2.util;
  exports org.codehaus.stax2.validation;
}

edit 2: no idea what is going on here, but mvn clean test seems to get my project to a point where I can at least run tests in Intellij. Thanks everyone who provided suggestions below!
Almost Solution
│ 1753 │ mvn clean package                               # passes
| 1754 | mvn test -Dtest=MyTest                          # failure                                                                                   
│ 1755 │ mvn clean test -Dtest=MyTest                    # passes                                                                                
│ 1756 │ mvn test -Dtest=MyTest                          # passes 
| 1757 | mvn test-compile                                # passes 
| 1758 | mvn clean package                               # passes 
| 1759 | mvn test-compile                                # failure 


[edit] clarifications into your question instead of using comments.

Do an mvn dependency:list on your project and post that in your question...

@khmarbaise thanks for stopping by! I'd love to post whatever specific information I can provide to help pin this dow, but since this isn't an open source project, I'd rather not post the full output ofdependency:list. Is there anything particular you're looking for?
@tgdavies good point - just removed my comment and added the extra content into section 4 :)

Can you upgrade the maven-compiler-plugin to the most recent version (3.13.0) https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

@khmarbaise great idea! I tried, but alas [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.13.0:compile (default-compile) on project _: Compilation failure [ERROR] module not found: org.codehaus.stax2. I got this by adding a  section for maven-compiler-plugin

Please create an example project... that shows the behaviour... In the post you have listed some parts which are working and some which are don't ... So also it is required to check all plugin version if they are on the most recent versions (for example maven-surefire-plugin for running your tests etc..
